domain/phpmyadmin 502 but domain work greatly
url/phpmyadmin said 502 error using nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
in error log :
2024/08/28 20:10:03 [crit] 2409#2409: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock
 failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 2.184.15.240, server: url, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock:", host: "host"

also used this command to restart
sudo systemctl restart php8.3-fpm

but error still not changed
here is /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name your_domain.com.com wwwyour_domain.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/Certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/Private_key.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/CA_Bundle.crt;

    # Optional settings for enhanced security
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";


    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm8.3.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }




    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    }


     location /phpmyadmin {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;  # Adjust the PHP version accordingly
    }


    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name your_domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

